# how to Make a form to always stay in desktop...in vb.net c#

Tags: .net, winforms, forms

i want to make a form that is perfectly fixed in desktop...it doesnt come when other application r opened and niether comes when the same form is clicked....stay fixed in desktop like icons in desktop....

Comment: So, you want the user to be unable to interact with your form at all? It shouldn't get focus when you click on it, they shouldn't be able to move it around or resize it, and they shouldn't be able to hide it from view? Looks like I won't be installing that.

Comment: i want the form to stick in desktop....same how my computer icons work...when we click it opens the drives....like that i will have buttons in form when i click it open sthe other...but the form should stay in desktop.....suppose u open a page in explorer and click on this form it comes in the front ...i dont want it to come in front of any other ...pther than desk top

Comment: The icons are actually *part* of the desktop. That doesn't mean the desktop is extensible. It's not designed to have random application windows attached to it, and that will cause all kinds of problems if you ever manage to get it to work. Did you read the [article I linked to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx)?What you need to do is just manage the Z order of your application. Something like `Form.SendToBack()`, not attaching it to the desktop window. You're not part of the desktop. You're nothing like an icon.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=351533

Try that out? I think that is what you're looking for. I wasn't able to test it myself, but the description seems to match what you are looking for to the best of my understanding.

Comment: That page has the vb.net code. There is also a link at the top of the post for c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern int  SetParent(int   hWndChild, int   hWndNewParent)
```

hWndChild is handle of your form and hWndNewParent is desktop handle

Comment: -1 This is a **terrible** suggestion. **You should not abuse the desktop window**. It's the same principle you learned in kindergarten: don't mess with things that aren't yours. Calling `SetParent` to make your form a child of the desktop window will cause the window manager to synchronize the desktop's input queue to your child window, which will cause all sorts of problems. See Raymond Chen's [blog article on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx) for all the gory details.